# Parsing a time-string, Python

Tags: python, locale, strptime

I struggle parsing a date/time-string with `datetime.strptime`:

```
date = "30. Dez 2016 19:34"
format = "%d. %b %Y %H:%M"
dt = datetime.strptime(date, format)
dt
```

Raises a value error:

```
ValueError: time data '30. Dez 2016 19:34' does not match format '%d. %b %Y %H:%M'
```

The string uses a german convention, i.e. "Dez" for december. I checked my locale with `locale.getlocale()` which seems to be ok: `('de_DE', 'UTF-8')`. Replacing the "Dez" with the english "Dec" works fine, though. I also checked the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) which suggests to me that it should work out of the box:

> Because the format depends on the current locale, care should be taken when making assumptions about the output value.

**EDIT**

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')
```

does it. Which still leaves me a bit unsatisfied, since my locale seemed to be fitting in the first place. If someone can shed some more light…

Comment: What happens if you set your locale manually before running your code? If I use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` then run your code from above I see the correct value.

Comment: Now that was easy. Thx. It works. I saw people doing it but I didn't dare to try, because I somehow didn't want to mess with the locale. Is it safe?

Comment: Don't see any reason it wouldn't be, if that is indeed your locale.

Comment: I'd try limiting it to just the date/time stuff: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')` just in case.

Comment: Well, it is. So me bravehearting ahead. Appreciated.

Comment: You can get your old locale back afterwards by `loc = locale.getlocale()`, `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')`, doing the stuff you want to do, `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, loc[0])`